# Regex for "don't"

Tags: regex

Can somebody help me with this regular expression pattern creation.

I want to match `"dont"` in `"don't"`. Likewise, `"do'nt"` should match `"don't"`.

Is there any way for this?

Comment: but there's not a `dont` in `don't`

Comment: `don't` attempt to use regex for such `dont`ing (daunting) tasks.

Comment: Are you asking how to ignore apostrophes? Just remove apostrophes from the text and from the search pattern, then search in the result.

Comment: You could do something like `s/(don)'(t)/\1\2/`…

Comment: Thank you all for your `very` valuable comments. I thought this is a very genuine scenario.

Comment: @BabuJames what's your use case, I most likely suggest Sneftel's comment.

Comment: @Sam: Say I have this string: "I don't smoke". I want to replace "don't" with "<i>don't</i>" when a user enters "dont" in a textbox.

Comment: @BabuJames I don't understand.  Did you mean to say that you want to replace `"dont"` with `"<i>don't</i>"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like `/d'?o'?n'?t/`, which looks for optional `'` in between every character.  You could also make a function out of this (PHP):

```
function addOptionalApostrophes($word)
{
    return preg_replace('/([a-z])(?=[a-z])/i', "$1'?$2", $word);
}

$string = "I do'nt smoke.";
$html_string = preg_replace('/(' . addOptionalApostrophes('dont') . ')/i', '<i>$1</i>', $string);

echo $html_string;
// I <i>do'nt</i> smoke.
```

The regex `/([a-z])(?=[a-z])/i`, matches an alphabetical character followed by a look ahead alphabetical character.  And then replaces `$1` (the first character) with `$1'?`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a set of certain misspellings, right?  So just check for those misspellings.

```
/\b(dont|don't|do'nt)\b/
```